# Unity5 C#: How to rotate a GameObject with touch drag

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a cube in my scene which I want to to rotate as player touch and drag it. here is the code

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit);

if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) &&  hit.collider.name == "Cube")
{
    xDeg -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed * friction;
    yDeg += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed * friction;
    fromRotation = cube.transform.rotation;
    toRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yDeg,xDeg,0);
    cube.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromRotation,toRotation,Time.deltaTime  * lerpSpeed);
}
```

I am 100% able to do that, problem is I have placed several other game objects with colliders on each wall of cube. All I want is player to be able to rotate cube around and perform some action by tapping on specific game objects on each wall. here is the rest of code

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    Ray ray1 = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray1, out hit)) {
        if (hit.collider.name == "ABC") {
            //Perform action specific to ABC
        }   
     }
 }
```

Now if I try rotating the cube it runs ABC (because definitely rayCast work it suppose to be). I can't figure out how I actually achieve this that player became able to rotate the cube by touch and drag as well as perform some action by just tapping on walls of same cube.

Comment: Did you check this with your device? Did you tried this...

Answer (score 0):

Put your cube collider in a different layer than the other objects.  Then call the version of Physics.Raycast that takes a layerMask.